# How can I get uploaded text file in view through Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm now making web app. This app gets text file having not-organized data and organize it. I'm now using Django in Python3.

I already made form data in templates.

- Teplates

```html
>    <form action="/practice/kakao_reader/" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
>        File:
>        <input type="file" name="file"/>
>        <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
>     </form>
```

But I have difficulty in getting uploaded file through VIEW.
The first code that I've tried was

- View.py

> def kakao_reader(request):
>
> f = codecs.open(request.FILES['file'], encoding = 'utf-8')
>
> data = f.read()

And I get  ***invalid file: InMemoryUploadedFile:*** this error.

The specific Error is

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8000/practice/kakao_reader/
>
> Django Version: 1.10 Python Version: 3.5.2 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'elections',  'practice'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Django\mysite\practice\views.py" in kakao_json
>     43.     f = codecs.open(request.FILES['file'], encoding = 'utf-8')
>
> File "C:\Python35\Lib\codecs.py" in open
>     895.     file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /practice/kakao_reader/ Exception Value:
>   invalid file:

How can I fix it? thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`request.FILES['file']` is already a file handler, so you don't have to open it. Just use `request.FILES['file'].read()`.